# Checking for New Entries in Firestore - Local Storage

Tags: firebase, vue.js, local-storage, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

So I have a Firestore database where i have all my posts in, I push them on page load into the store so I can have a fast navigation and only need to fetch once.

What I wanna do now is to use a persisted state so i dont need to refetch it if the user opens a new window or F5(reloads) the page.

The problem is im not sure how to check if new Posts are in the Firestore without querying all posts and I havent found any methods to do it in a healthy and Read efficient way.

Comment: What have you tried so far? :)

Comment: @AndreyPopov i havent implemented the localStorage logic yet because im not certain on how to check for differences between firestore and the local storage without using tons of reads which would make it inefficient and poentless.

Comment: There should be a method to query posts from specific time period, right? Get the last post from your local storage, and then get all posts from fire base that are AFTER this time ;)

Comment: @AndreyPopov oh yes i actually save a timestamp on the post creation, so i guess logic would be if the user first time visits -> fetch into localStorage; second visit -> check for new posts after latest timestamp, ok i will try it out in terms of speed thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no super easy way around it - at the end you have some data, and the server has another, you need to check for differences.

If you're only trying to figure out if there are new posts on the backend, which are not loaded on your frontend, then just get the date on your last post, and then ask Firebase for all posts after this date :)

Of course if you don't have posts, ask for everything.

Keep in mind you need to manually check if posts are deleted ;)

Comment: Oh yes the deletion part will make it a bit more complicated... or in general when Edits to a post happen, well i try to find a solution for that :)

Answer (score -1):

Realtime updates with the onSnapshot method can be used to keep local data in sync with the server. If you initially load it into vuex then subsequent changes on server side will be reflected automatically.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

To share one set of data across tabs/windows you could look at something like this

https://github.com/xanf/vuex-shared-mutations